# React jest testing: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-props

I am testing  a react component with jest. it gives the bellow mention error in the terminal. can somebody help me to solve this. here I have attached my js file and its test file.

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR

```
 FAIL  src/features/dashboard/components/jest-tests/ExpandedInstancDetails.test.js (19.767 s)
  ExpandedInstancDetails component
    × navigation of the page to nxt page (216 ms)

  ● ExpandedInstancDetails component › navigation of the page to nxt page

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

      25 |           </Text>
      26 |           <Text className="poppins expanded-content-id">
    > 27 |             ID :{props.instanceDetails.id}
         |                                        ^
      28 |           </Text>
      29 |         </div>
      30 |

      at ExpandedInstancDetails (src/features/dashboard/components/ExpandedInstancDetails.js:27:40)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14803:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17482:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18596:16)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188:14)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:338:25)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
      at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237:16)
      at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:292:31)
      at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23203:7)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22157:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22130:22)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21756:9)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21188:7)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24373:3)
      at node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24758:7
      at unbatchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21903:12)
      at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24757:5)
      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24840:10)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:101:25
      at batchedUpdates$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21856:12)
      at act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:929:14)
      at render (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:97:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/dashboard/components/jest-tests/ExpandedInstancDetails.test.js:36:27)
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ExpandedInstancDetails.js

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/ExpandedInstancDetails.less";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import ExpandedInstanceSchedule from "./ExpandedInstanceShedule";
import { Typography } from "antd";
import moment from "moment";
const { Text } = Typography;

const ExpandedInstancDetails = (props) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const MoreDetailsClick = () => {
    history.push({
      pathname: "/dashboard/instancedetails",
      state: { instanceId: "i-0b3db6cb7bebde704" },
    });
  //   history.push( "/dashboard/instancedetails");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="expanded-content">
        <div className="expanded-content-title-section">
          <Text className="poppins expanded-content-title">
            Instance Details
          </Text>
          <Text className="poppins expanded-content-id">
            ID :{props.instanceDetails.id}
          </Text>
        </div>

        <div className="expanded-detail-section">
         <div className="expanded-detail-box-type">
            <div className="expanded-detail-box-content">
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-title">
                TYPE
              </Text>
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-value">
                {props.instanceDetails.type}
              </Text>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="expanded-detail-box-lounchtime">
            <div className="expanded-detail-box-content">
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-title">
                LOUNCHTIME
              </Text>
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-value">
              {props.instanceDetails.launchTime}
              </Text>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="expanded-detail-box-region">
            <div className="expanded-detail-box-content">
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-title">
                REGION
              </Text>
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-value">
                {props.instanceDetails.region}
              </Text>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="expanded-detail-box-1">
            <div className="expanded-detail-box-content">
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-title">
                SUBNET ID
              </Text>
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-value">
                {props.instanceDetails.subnetId}
              </Text>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="expanded-detail-box-2">
            <div className="expanded-detail-box-content">
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-title">
                VPC ID
              </Text>
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-value">
                {props.instanceDetails.vpcId}
              </Text>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="expanded-detail-box-3">
            <div className="expanded-detail-box-content">
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-title">
                AVAILABILITY ZONE
              </Text>
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-value">
                {props.instanceDetails.availabilityZone}
              </Text>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="expanded-detail-box-4">
            <div className="expanded-detail-box-content">
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-title">
                CREATION TIME
              </Text>
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-value">
                {props.instanceDetails.launchTime}
              </Text>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="expanded-detail-box-5">
            <div className="expanded-detail-box-content">
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-title">
                PRIVATE IP ADDRESS
              </Text>
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-value">
                {props.instanceDetails.privateIpAddress}
              </Text>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="expanded-detail-box-6">
            <div className="expanded-detail-box-content">
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-title">
                PUBLIC IP ADDRESS
              </Text>
              <Text className="poppins expanded-content-detail-value">
                {props.instanceDetails.publicIpAddress}
              </Text>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 

        <Text
          className="poppins expanded-content-pointer-button"
          data-testid="button"          
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={MoreDetailsClick}
        >
          more details
        </Text>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ExpandedInstancDetails ;
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ExpandedInstancDetails.test.js

```
import { render, screen, act, getByTestId } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import ExpandedInstancDetails from "../ExpandedInstancDetails";
import { shallow, configure } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { MoreDetailsClick } from "../ExpandedInstancDetails";
import reactRouterDom from "react-router-dom";

const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("ExpandedInstancDetails component", () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();

  const props = {
    id: "100",
    type: "Total Instances",
    launchTime: "TotalInstances.svg",
    region: "Total Instances",
    subnetId: "Total Instances",
    vpcId: "Total Instances",
    availabilityZone: "Total Instances",
    launchTime: "Total Instances",
    privateIpAddress: "Total Instances",
    publicIpAddress: "Total Instances",
  };

  it("navigation of the page to nxt page", () => {
    const { getByRole } = render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <ExpandedInstancDetails props={props} onClick={MoreDetailsClick} />
      </Router>
    );

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/more details/i));
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/dashboard/instancedetails");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hello as per your props data there is no `instanceDetail` you can re-check props

```
const props = {
    id: "100",
    type: "Total Instances",
    launchTime: "TotalInstances.svg",
    region: "Total Instances",
    subnetId: "Total Instances",
    vpcId: "Total Instances",
    availabilityZone: "Total Instances",
    launchTime: "Total Instances",
    privateIpAddress: "Total Instances",
    publicIpAddress: "Total Instances",
  };
```

Here you have `id` directly inside props so you should try

```
<Text className="poppins expanded-content-id">
            ID :{props.id}
          </Text>
```

I hope this will solve your error Or if you want `props.instanceDetail.id` then you have to change your props object as following

```
const props = {
    instanceDetail : {
        id: "100"
    },
    ...
  };
```